# Inputting a value in to each cell in a 2D range based on what info is in the cell in the start of each row and column

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project that has a variable sized range, based on the inputs on another sheet. It currently uses check boxes and a filter function to determine what is the name in each row, and each column has a numerical value based on other criteria.

Currently I have it checking each row "title" and then running a sub routine based on this.

```
Sub Resource1()

If Cell.Value(F11) = "A" Then
    Call PM
ElseIf Cell.Value(F11) = "B" Then
    Call Des
ElseIf Cell.Value(F11) = "C" Then
    Call Tes
ElseIf Cell.Value(F11) = "D" Then
    Call Sim
ElseIf Cell.Value(F11) = "E" Then
    Call EBU
ElseIf Cell.Value(F11) = "F" Then
    Call EPG
ElseIf Cell.Value(F11) = "G" Then
    Call Pro
ElseIf Cell.Value(F11) = "H" Then
    Call Req
ElseIf Cell.Value(F11) = "I" Then
    Call Oth
    
Else: End

End Sub
```

I then have to run this for each of a possible of 9 rows, before going to the sub routine to Loop again for the value in the "title" of the columns which there are 72 of. I intended to do a For Each per row so that I could have a set offset. I have also tried to do this via an array, but had no luck with that.

Is there a function that I can use to check the start of each row and column and input data that way? It seems intuitive from a simple to explain example, but I am pretty new to VBA and

Comment: I'm still a little confused on what you want done. Maybe if you shared one of your subs( `PM`, `Des`, or `Tes` ... ) it would be easier to understand

Comment: Here is what I am trying to work out. 

Sub PM()

Dim cel As Range


For Each cel In Range("H11:CA11")
    If cel.Offset(287, 0) = "7" Then cel.Value = "40"
        ElseIf cel.Offset(287, 0) = "6" Then cel.Value = "50"
        ElseIf cel.Offset(287, 0) = "5" Then cel.Value = "60"
        ElseIf cel.Offset(287, 0) = "4" Then cel.Value = "70"
        ElseIf cel.Offset(287, 0) = "3" Then cel.Value = "80"
        ElseIf cel.Offset(287, 0) = "2" Then cel.Value = "90"
        ElseIf cel.Offset(287, 0) = "1" Then cel.Value = "100"
    Else: End If
        
Next
        

End Sub